# Scripting a website-opener

Tags: python, file-io, python-webbrowser

I'm using a python script to take in a file containing a bunch of website URLs and open all of them in new tabs. However, I'm getting an error message when opening the first website: this is what I get:

> 0:41: execution error: "https://www.pandora.com/
>   " doesn’t understand the “open location” message. (-1708)

My script thus far looks like this:

```
import os
import webbrowser
websites = []
with open("websites.txt", "r+") as my_file:
    websites.append(my_file.readline())
for x in websites:
    try:
        webbrowser.open(x)
    except:
        print (x + " does not work.")
```

My file consists of a bunch of URLs on their own lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running your code and it works on my machine with python 2.7.9

It may be a character encoding issue when you are trying to open the file

This is my suggestion with the following edits:

```
import webbrowser

with open("websites.txt", "r+") as sites:
   sites =  sites.readlines()      # readlines returns a list of all the lines in your file, this makes code more concise
                                   # In addition we can use the variable 'sites' to hold the list returned to us by the file object 'sites.readlines()'


print sites               # here we send the output of the list to the shell to make sure it contains the right information

for url in sites:
    webbrowser.open_new_tab( url.encode('utf-8') )   # this is here just in-case, to encode characters that the webbrowser module can interpret
                                                            # sometimes special characters like '\' or '/' can cause issues for us unless we encode/decode them or make them raw strings
```

Hope this helps!